# How to fetch all the ActivityTypes within multiple Azure Data Factory Pipelines using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/get-azdatafactoryactivitywindow?view=azps-5.0.0

When I run the following commands, I get all the Linked Services and Pipelines for the Datafactory

```
Get-AzDataFactoryV2LinkedService -ResourceGroupName "xxxxxxxxx" -DataFactoryName "xxxxxxxxxxx" 

Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName "xxxxxxxxx" -DataFactoryName "xxxxxxxxx"
```

But when the following is executed from the same powershell module, I get an error

```
PS C:\>Get-AzDataFactoryActivityWindow -DataFactoryName "xxxxxxxx" -ResourceGroupName "xxxxxxx"

Error: Get-AzDataFactoryActivityWindow: 
HTTP Status Code: NotFound
Error Code: ResourceNotFound
Error Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.DataFactory/dataFactories/xxxxxxx' under resource group 'xxxxxxxxx' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
Request Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Timestamp (Utc):11/13/2020 00:37:24

Requirement is to pull all the ActivityType from the list of pipelines I have in Datafactory


ResourceGroupName : ADF
DataFactoryName   : WikiADF
PipelineName      : DP_WikipediaSamplePipeline
ActivityName      : WikiHiveActivity
**ActivityType      : HDInsightHive
LinkedServiceName : HDILinkedService**
WindowState       : Ready
WindowSubstate    : 
Duration          : 00:03:37.8020000
InputDatasets     : {DA_WikipediaClickEvents}
OutputDatasets    : {DA_CuratedWikiData}
PercentComplete   : 100
RunAttempts       : 1
RunStart          : 8/17/2016 11:09:23 PM
RunEnd            : 8/17/2016 11:13:01 PM
WindowStart       : 8/17/2016 3:00:00 AM
WindowEnd         : 8/17/2016 4:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and in the future be sure to [format your code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. It seems that we cannot get information about activity windows associated with a data factory from powershell due to safety reasons.

As an alternative, we can get all the informations from ADF UI. Click export `Export ARM template` to download the arm templates. We can see the `arm template.json`, which contains informations of the activities.
[image]